# Проблема с запуском локального сервера для проекта на Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

склонировал проект и не могу его запустить локально.

Применял вот эти команды

npm install -g @angular/cli7.1.2

npm install @angular/cli@7.1.2

npm install node-sass

npm install

npm audit fix

cd web (зашел в проект)

ng serve --open (и тут ошибки)

В целом пробовал устанавливать Ангулар как глобально так и локально, но при запуске проекта ошибка. Прошу писать ответы развёрнуто, я новичёк, могу не понять вас.

Вот что появляется при установке Англугара

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так там же прямо в тексте и написано, что немного пакетов не хватает. установите их. И если что, проект пишется через **е**, а не **э**, хотя и звучит как будто э.

Comment: Как установить недостоющие пакеты? откуда взять ссылки и они через терминал уснанавливаются?

Comment: похоже, ребята с  npm не очень хотят, что бы их продуктом пользовались. Они удалили автоматическое скачивание. Вам нужно ручками докачать их с помощью команды `npm install --save-dev  <пакет>` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053414/npm-warn-requires-a-peer-of-but-none-is-installed-you-must-install-peer?rq=1)

Comment: Понял но как в каждом WARN найти слово которое нужно вставить в <пакет> npm install --save-dev  <пакет>. Что бы его скачать

Comment: А вам и не надо вписывать это вручную. Для таких целей придумали файл package.json. В нем хранится список всех пакетов, которые должны быть установлены. Если вы запустите команду npm i в папке с этим файлом, то все пакеты будут установлены автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала `cd web`, а потом уже все остальные манипуляции. и не забывайте флаг `--save` для `npm install`, чтобы ваши зависимости сохранялись в package.json. Или (как вариант) используйте boilerplate наподобие этого - https://github.com/mdbootstrap/Angular-Bootstrap-Boilerplate